# Is it possible to change color of a single property Value in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#

Is it possible to change color of a single property Value in PropertyGrid.Suppose I have 10 properties in PropertyGrid. I want to change the font color of a single property Value. How can i do that?

Answer (score -1):

Ofcourse, you can use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.

Comment: I you would expand more on this. Just pasting a link is frowned upon here. See [Provide Context For Links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)